# How to call Async API in Spring Boot using RestTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate, asyncresttemplate

I am in a need of calling a api asynchronously in my spring boot application? Is there any methods that we can used in Spring RestTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemplate may not be a good idea. As per documentation, [AsyncRestClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) exposes similar methods as RestTemplate, but returns `ListenableFuture` wrappers as opposed to concrete results. Also, [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) would be a much better choice over AsyncRestClient which is deprecated. As the linked page shows it is

> Deprecated.  as of Spring 5.0, in favor of WebClient